# What are all the episodes and scenes of Legend of Korra that feature bloodbending on people?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

A friend of mine has recently started watching Legend of Korra, however they've just explained to me how, for very personal reasons, they aren't comfortable watching the effects of bloodbending.

I have a very hazy memory of the first season of LoK, and past that I didn't watch it.

Is there a list of episodes that include bloodbending available, and possibly timestamps? If possible without spoilers.

This should help them either avoid or at least prepare for when bloodbending is shown on screen.

Comment: Possibly a start: https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Bloodbending

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza that isn't a bad start, but it doesn't make it super clear which episodes it's in

Comment: There are a bunch of scenes in LoK season 1 that people don't realize are bloodbending until much later in the season (anytime Amon takes people's bending away). Does that count re your friend's list?

Comment: Also, pretty much all of season 1 is about bloodbending when it comes down to it--it's the main ability of the villain, the main thrust of the backstory, etc. Even when it's not depicted it's relevant and explored. Would it make more sense for your friend to just skip season 1 entirely?

Comment: @Kitkat yes I think those scenes where isn't not obvious would count

Comment: Ok--then honestly it might make sense for your friend to just skip season 1 (at least episode 3 and on) if they're uncomfortable with both the depiction and effects/discussion of bloodbending--it's basically the whole plot.

Comment: @kitkat just spoke to my friend, and those parts (the fake energy bending) are not the issue.

Comment: Ok, so it's just where someone's body is held still/made to move by bloodbending?

Comment: @kitkat Yes that's right

Answer (score 2):

Examples of bloodbending only being used to remove bending are not listed, in accordance with the asker's clarification. I also didn't include the recaps from the beginning of each episode that show scenes from previous episodes.

---

1.8 *When Extremes Meet*

- Tarlok's fight with Korra, until the end of the episode

1.9 *Out of the Past*

- The opening scene
- The first and second sepia-toned flashbacks
- the confrontation with Tarlok
- Tarlok's fight with Amon

1.11 *Skeletons in the Closet*

- Tarrlok's backstory scenes

1.12 *Endgame*

- The scene where Korra hides from Amon, until Amon is thrown out a window

2.14 *Light in the Dark*

- When looking at Korra's memories in the Tree of Time, a brief scene of her being bloodbent can be seen

4.8 *Remembrances*

- During Korra's flashback